# Store different Function return types in one union in C

Tags: c, unions

I am having troubles formulating my objective in words so I am not too sure on how to express this.

Say I have two functions with the following signatures:

```
myBigStruct_t function1()
int function2()
```

with a definition of myBigStruct_t (that stores a lot of data and is somewhere else) and a union definition that can support the size of both return types:

```
typedef union myUnion{
   myBigStruct_t A;
   int B;
} myData_t;

union my2ndUnion{
   myData_t data_;
   char myArray[sizeOf(myData_t)];
} un2;
```

Can I do the following:

```
un2.myArray = function1();
...
if( something ){
   myExpress = un2.data_.A; 
else{
   myOtherExpress = un2.data_.B;
}
...
un2.myArray = function2();
if( something ){
   myExpress = un2.data_.A; 
else{
   myOtherExpress = un2.data_.B;
}
```

I know array data is normally passed by reference but most C compilers have a means of passing large data types that at least appear to be by value (regardless of whether or not a secret pointer is used).

I know its a bit contrived; I am just trying to get my ahead around unions.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is. The only question I see is "Can I do the following", the compiler should tell you if the code compiles (and thus if you "can" do it). What are you actually trying to learn?

Comment: Is it possible to store the return values from various functions, where the return values are of diverse size, into something like a union? (Like I said having a really hard time phrasing this)

Comment: You can't assign to an array.

Comment: I will clarify my question as follows:

Comment: Acknowledging that handling function return values by passing in a pointer for the return value [for instance "void myFunc(myReturnType * myReturnValue)"] is the more extensible way of dealing with this problem, I am constrained by functions of the form "myReturnType myFunc()."

That said: 

I was wondering if there was a way to typecast the return value of a function (in the form "myReturnType myFunc1()") to a union so that I could handle the return values of multiple different functions (with different function prototypes (e.g. "myReturnType2 myFunc2()")) in a more extensible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what unions do. I think that answers your question (let me know if it doesn't), but I'll give some more background.

If `myBigStruct_t` is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char someChars[256];
    int  someInts[512];
} myBigStruct_t;
```

Then when you do the assignment from `function1()`, the data is copied. There is no secret pointer involved.

On the other hand, if `myBigStruct_t` is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char *someChars; //This gets malloc'd in function1
    int  *someInts; //This gets malloc'd in function1
} myBigStruct_t;
```

Then the data is passed by reference, i.e. the data was not copied.

Note that your code as-is won't work because of the type mismatch between the return values of `function1` and `myArray`, and the same for `function2`. You'll have to assign the specific union members:

```
un2.myArray.data_.A = function1();
un2.myArray.data_.B = function2();
```

I don't think there's any reason not to do it this way.

### Edit (in response to your comment):

Why not just pass the array as a parameter instead of return value? A function prototype would be like: `void foo(void* buffer, size_t buffer_len)`. I assume you fully understand pointers (otherwise function pointers are probably not the right way to solve your problem). A complete program might look like:

```
//All the functions use this prototype, although it isn't strictly necessary (your loop would just have to be smarter)
typedef void(*GenericFunctionCall)(void* buffer, size_t buffer_len);

//A struct with only a few bytes
typedef struct SmallStruct_s{
    char value;
} SmallStruct_t;

//A struct with more bytes
typedef struct BigStruct_s {
    char value[1024];
} BigStruct_t;

//Defining this makes it easy to get the maximum size of all the structs
typedef union AllStructs_s {
    SmallStruct_t small;
    BigStruct_t big;
} AllStructs_t;

//This function takes the buffer, casts it to a SmallStruct_t, and then does something with it (presumably sets param->value to something)
void smallFunction(void* buffer, size_t buffer_len) {
    SmallStruct_t * param = (SmallStruct_t*)buffer;

    //do something with param
}
    //This function does the same with BigStruct_t
void bigFunction(void* buffer, size_t buffer_len) {
    BigStruct_t * param = (BigStruct_t*)buffer;

    //do something with param
}



int main() {
    //This allocates memory for all the values generated by smallFunction and bigFunction.
    AllStructs_t param;

    //This is your table of function pointers
    GenericFunctionCall functions[2];
    functions[0] = smallFunction;
    functions[1] = bigFunction;

    //Loop through the functions and do something with the results
    for (uint32_t function_index = 0; function_index < 2; ++function_index) {
        functions[function_index]((void*)&param, sizeof(AllStructs_t));

        //Do something with param here
    }
}
```

### Second edit:

Okay I now see what you're trying to do. You can't use union between to accept an arbitrary value, in this case unions are no different from any other data type (i.e. I can't assign BigStruct_t = SmallStruct_t).

Here's why: when the compiler generates code to handle the return value of a function, it is using the caller's memory to store the value. Because of that, you're not allowed to get a pointer to the return value for a function. In compiler-speak: the return value of a function is not an [lvalue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx). The options for solving this are:

- Store the return type of the function in the table, and use that assign the appropriate variable
- Write a wrapper function for each function from the table, and have it convert the return type from return value to pointer parameter. Call the wrapper instead of the original function
- Refactor the code completely

Comment: I have a table of function pointers.  Each function's return type has a different size; it is entirely possible that the size of the return type is also stored in that table.  I want to create a loop that can call any function in the table of function pointers and then copy the data off into an array.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense, I edited my answer accordingly. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I agree that passing the return value as a pointer would solve this problem.  Unfortunately, I am confined by pre-existing design decisions and the return value has to be the function return value not a block of memory passed by reference to the function.

Comment: I have used the methodology you suggested in your edited post in the past to great success.  It was for this reason that I was trying to figure out how to take care of this problem in the way I suggested by somehow typecasting the return value to a struct/union.  It doesn't look like C supports this though; unless you can correct me?

(Since my question seems less stupid now, would you mind voting it up to get me out of the negatives?)

Comment: I updated my answer again. If you want an upvote, could you clarify the question with the information you've provided here so that a future reader could better understand what you are trying to accomplish? Try describing what your problem is, instead of your proposed solution.